# Background image not showing when in external style sheet

Tags: css, image, background

Don't know what's going on, but for some reason my background image is not showing when linked in external style sheet.

Example1: (working)

```
<html>
<head>
    ...
</head>
<body style="background: url(images/image.jpg);">
    ...
</body>
</html>
```

Example2: (non-working - external css file)

```
body {
    background: url(images/image.jpg);
}
```

The image is displays when/if I use the first example, but no image is displayed when I use the second one.

Any suggestions? Thank you in advanced...

Comment: can you provide the levels of directories these three files are stored in?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The directory your external CSS file is stored in may be different from the directory of the page you are putting the inline styles on. You may need to start your path with a slash.

```
url(/images/image.jpg)
```

or perhaps go back a directory like

```
url(../images/image.jpg)
```

Comment: You know what, I was adding ./, but never tried ../. It worked. Thank you.